# Including a quote in a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm writing my thesis and would love to begin my bibliography with the famous line from the Talmud:

"a person who cites his source brings deliverance to the world" (Avot 6:5)

That is i am using the \bibliography command, and I'd like to place the quote between the heading and the list of cited sources

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`?

Comment: no `natbib` :) :) :)

Comment: I asked because it's easier to customise bibliographies with biblatex.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

With natbib you can normally redefine \bibpreamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{doody}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\def\bibpreamble{Some text before the bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just in case you decide to switch to biblatex:

```
\defbibnote{myprenote}{Here goes my text.}
\printbibliography[prenote=myprenote]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `epigraph` package (`< texdoc epigraph` section 2.6 *Epigraphed bibliographies*). The code given there can also be used, with appropriate edits, to add epigraphs to other things like indexes or abstracts.